# Building LINQ queries

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, codeplex

Has anybody evaluated [this codeplex project](http://linqtextquerybuilder.codeplex.com/)?

Are there any limits (or bugs or exceptions) when using `queryBuilder.Query`?

It would save much of my time instead of using other LINQ variants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not seen this project before, but it looks like it is just compiling the C# query into a dynamic assembly using CodeDOM. Here is a blog post on how it works:

http://kenanbek.com/site/post/dynamic-linq-queries-build-linq-queries-from-text-at-runtime/

If it is using dynamic compilation then it probably does not have many limitations. It will only be able to access items off the object you pass into the `LinqTextQueryBuilder.SetSource()` method, of course.

I am using something similar called Dynamic Linq in a project I work on, but it is more for parsing where clause expressions and the like rather than than entire queries. It works slightly different in that it parses a C#-like expression directly into an expression tree, rather than using CodeDOM and a dynamic assembly as an intermediary. Therefore, it is probably a bit faster, but more limited.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Depending on scenario, the AsExpandable and PredicateBuilder parts of LINQKit are very useful as well in my experience.

http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx